# Which DBZ episode is the "Thanks, but I am already dead" meme from?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z, meme

There is a common meme on the internet where Vegeta says "Thanks, but I am already dead". ([YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjYsO94SzDA))

[image]

What episode/movie is this from?

Answer (score 2):

It's the Dragon Ball Z series, Buu Saga, episode 281, "Minute of desperation", minute 13:20. I dont think I can link the episode live here since they have copyright, but it's this episode described in the DBZ Wikia.

[Minute of desperation](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Minute_of_Desperation)

Comment: Oh Thanks! I see why this never caught my attention!  This is a dub only meme. People who watch anime in Japanese and don't care about English probably missed this one. This is one of those scenes were the dub changed the original text. In Japanese this was "Don't die." and Vegeta replied "that is not your problem".